# Working with XSLT Variables

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML:
(it's in Portuguese but I guess it really doesn't matter)

```
    <xml_tube>
    <utilizadores>
        <utilizador username="Guicky" password="futurama96">
            <nome>Guilherme Luís</nome>
            <birthday>1996-11-28</birthday>
            <foto href="guilhas.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
        <utilizador username="Daisy" password="woofwoof11">
            <nome>Daisy Luís</nome>
            <birthday>2011-04-04</birthday>
            <foto href="daisy.png"/>
        </utilizador>
        <utilizador username="Anabela65" password="crumble65">
            <nome>Anabela Ribeiro</nome>
            <birthday>1965-04-02</birthday>
            <foto href="belinha.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
        <utilizador username="Izzie" password="lagartixa">
            <nome>Isadora Luís</nome>
            <birthday>1988-06-27</birthday>
            <foto href="izzie.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
    </utilizadores>
    <videos_pub>
        <video id="Vid1" publisher="Daisy" duracao="3:37" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>Who let the dogs out? - Baha Men</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Qkuu0Lwb5EM/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>My favorite song, lol.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qkuu0Lwb5EM</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
            <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
            <related></related>
        </video>
        <video id="Vid2" publisher="Guicky" duracao="4:01" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>Desiigner - Timmy Turner</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/JzmRt2VgKYQ/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>Timmy Timmy Timmy Turner.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/ProbPpO_8oo</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
            <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
            <likes liked="Daisy"/>
            <related></related>
        </video>
        <video id="Vid3" publisher="Guicky" duracao="3:47" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe</título>
            <thumb>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2ak_oBeC-I</thumb>
            <descrição>Nothing can stop me, I'm all the way up.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/y2ak_oBeC-I</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <related></related>
        </video>
        <video id="Vid4" publisher="Anabela65" duracao="3:21" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>Putzgrilla - Sentadinha</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>Dá uma sentadinha.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC4JbIvIhdI</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
            <likes liked="Daisy"/>
            <related></related>
        </video>
        <video data="2017-01-13" duracao="02:16" id="Vid5" publisher="Izzie">
            <título>Yann Tiersen - La Valse d'Amelie</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uzurqBnALkw/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>A minha música preferida.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzurqBnALkw</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
            <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
            <related></related>
        </video>
    </videos_pub>
    <playlist>
        <lista owner="Guicky" dataIns="2016-10-24" id="PV1">
            <titulo>BEST MUSIC.</titulo>
            <descricao>Compilation of my favourite music videos.</descricao>
            <gostosL gostouL="Guicky"/>
            <links_vid vid="Vid2"/>
            <links_vid vid="Vid3"/>
            <administradores>
                <admin ref="Guicky"/>
                <admin ref="Daisy"/>
            </administradores>
            <editores>
                <editor ref="Guicky"/>
            </editores>
            <subscritores>
                <subs ref="Daisy"/>
                <subs ref="Anabela65"/>
            </subscritores>
            <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg"/>
        </lista>
        <lista owner="Anabela65" dataIns="2016-02-29" id="PV2">
            <titulo>Sentadinha!</titulo>
            <descricao>Siting lesson's with Guicky's mom!</descricao>
            <links_vid vid="Vid4"/>
            <administradores>
                <admin ref="Anabela65"/>
                <admin ref="Guicky"/>
            </administradores>
            <editores>
                <editor ref="Anabela65"/>
            </editores>
            <subscritores>
                <subs ref="Guicky"/>
                <subs ref="Daisy"/>
            </subscritores>
            <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg"/>
        </lista>
    </playlist>
    <comentarios>
        <comentario id="C1" refV="Vid1" user="Guicky" data="2016-10-23">
            <text>AHAHAHAHA, bom vídeo.</text>
            <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
            <respostas>
                <texto autor="Daisy">Grande clássico!</texto>
            </respostas>
        </comentario>
        <comentario id="C2" refL="Vid2" user="Anabela65" data="2016-10-22">
            <text>Timmy timmy timmy turner...</text>
            <gosto gostou="Guicky"/>
            <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
            <respostas>
                <texto autor="Guicky">U know it.</texto>
                <resposta autor="Daisy">LOL!</resposta>
            </respostas>
        </comentario>
    </comentarios>
</xml_tube>
```

Here is my XSLT:
(version 1.0)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="eng">
            <head>
                <title>My XML Tube</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="XML_Tube.css" charset="UTF-8"/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <link rel="icon" 
                      type="image.png"
                      href="favicon-16.png"/>   
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="spacer"/>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
                    <img id="img" src="img/logos/logo.png"/>
                </a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html">Playlists</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../XMLTube.xml#body">Playlist</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Playlists</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Utilizadores</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="Portfolio.html#NOSLeague">Um utilizador</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Portfolio.html#PremierLeague">Lista geral de utilizadores</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contacts.html">Vídeos</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="Contacts.html#gui">Vídeo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Contacts.html#rodri">Lista geral de vídeos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1>Lista de Utilizadores</h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="xml_tube/utilizadores">
                    <xsl:for-each select="utilizador">
                        <xsl:for-each select="foto">
                            <xsl:element name="img">
                                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="width">20%</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="height">auto</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:variable name="utilizadores" select="@username"/>
                    <p><strong>Username: </strong><xsl:value-of select="@username"/></p>
                    <p><strong>Nome: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="nome"/></p>
                    <p><strong>Birthday: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="birthday"/></p>
                        <p><strong>Vídeos Publicados:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="xml_tube/videos_pub/video[@publisher=$utilizadores]/título"/></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm having a problem with this specific part:

```
<xsl:variable name="utilizadores" select="@username"/>
        <p><strong>Username: </strong><xsl:value-of select="@username"/></p>
        <p><strong>Nome: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="nome"/></p>
        <p><strong>Birthday: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="birthday"/></p>
            <p><strong>Vídeos Publicados:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="xml_tube/videos_pub/video[@publisher=$utilizadores]/título"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to use the @username of the users that the `xsl:for-each` iterated on and use it to to search for the published vids of that @username.

Expected output:

```
Videos publicados: Vid1Vid3
```

My question is: How can i use the xsl:for-each to get me every username and then get me the videos of that specific username

Comment: What isn't working? What is the actual output? What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't output anything just the <p> part ("Vídeos publicados:"). I just added the question to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your variable, but with your XPath.. You are in the context of `utilizador` and from this context the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xml_tube/videos_pub/video[@publisher=$utilizadores]/título"/>
```

selects nothing, because `xml_tube` is not a child of `utilizador`.

You should be using an absolute path like:

```
/xml_tube/videos_pub/video[@publisher=$utilizadores]/título
```

and you should be using this within an `xsl:for-each` instruction - unless each `utilizador` has at most one `video`.

Even better, use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to resolve cross-references.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah I should've used the absolute path, it's working now though.